# Android Action Bar elliptical shadow

Tags: android, android-layout, svg, android-actionbar

I am trying to inset a drop shadow to the android action bar like the one shown in the figure below... Can someone help me how to achieve such a kind drop shadow?[image]

I tried to use an SVG for the shadow using the android library [here](https://github.com/japgolly/svg-android) but i am unable to achieve it.

Here is the svg code for the drop shadow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="640.036px" height="3.565px" viewBox="0 0 640.036 3.565" enable-background="new 0 0 640.036 3.565" xml:space="preserve">
<g opacity="0.6">

        <image overflow="visible" width="2967" height="315" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAC58AAAE9CAYAAAA2mTf1AAAACXBIWXMAAC4jAAAuIwF4pT92AAAA
GXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAFmlJREFUeNrs3d9vHMUBB/CZ3bMd
nGASJNKGtFWp1JdK/QOqSn3pCwie4E9DSPwT8ASCl75UqvoHIPUJUUQbUoJEEhO78Y/b6cydA9i+
qDHcnXdnPx/pfD9ebnZ2dnbG/s44BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAgKpEVcAqpZTCW2+8Ft//8OPZ+51bt1UKAAAAAAAAAAAAwJLs3r0ze37z9VfDex98lGIU
D2Z1JqqAVXr3nbebTz79rGknkyak1BzuPYqhR71a7FL+mUITm3DcTUvR9LgAAAAAAAAAAADAj5Ky
SdOGLnWh7BGdmrjyL2zbNoUYu08+/ax79523yxd3zgSrImjLSv3i5zcnX+3ubYXp8Xbu4LZyk2tD
06OA9zTlIpXwedsep2kbYyzdfBzedRxdzQAAAAAAAAAAANQhnf4xoGKX7Hk3ie20S9NpSDGEdsXh
vi6Vry277x6EdrL/s52rB//+z71jjYhVEVdlZV751S/j53e+3NzY2Hwhd6cv5T50J6awmVtdb9pd
7uRLWZoU41Z+czUXbSuXrs3l7P21cbIsqYTly38waPpUr/ofAAAAAAAAAACA3kkDKmkpa5d/lBB1
1wyhyHFW6mn+cRBi3IspP+eyxxjTqusqf/dh/pbd/L1fHx0dPvz17ZcP//nFv5ImzypMVAGr8tvf
vBK/+Ope7jfDRtel51KMz+debiv3sL25D+QylW59M4awkzvdm7kLfj5/uJlmy416bFbu1IZ5WP5q
fr2VZvWahhLoLlu1l3bQlkca2Ljm9HEAAAAAAAAAAAAVG3CA97sdTafzR+qGcTyx5Li7FONBTGEv
F/kgv56W3Wb73VJKyDwdxhi/ze/u5ePYLaHwkyD9Kr+4SyEe5Po5apq40UwmseQ3hc9ZXc8CK2xf
W5sbk9RMruZO7fo8JB02Uo926O5KAroEt2O8kbv327kTvpE/utL3EHeuwnJ33cxl3sllfSl/8kK+
S5QQ/RCu6Vj+kUgpfx4KbOfXub6fBNAH1XmW8PyTR1tZf+reAAAAAAAAAADAj5EqOo4S2C5h7bL7
djfEg3gSPM/lfxxj2I8pHKb5caWeV34J8B3mp4f5KL7OB7I7L3vPw+dhFj5/nJ/v5zLfiSnd72I8
aFZc33G+8/lRKEH9GB/E7njv4PDouKLrkX72LbAaf/7TH9u/f/KPyeH+3kbs0iQ0TZMfvWl3sevK
YqiNtm2vTlO6nrq0XVb+5C6319dGNwtwp61czBfzi5dzeV/MH28NZOfzONuxPYSyE/7N/Honv95M
A+qPTkL+7bzOw3aYB+ibgfepZVlIE+Y76g/9WNzvAAAAAAAAAIAhSPUdT+rCbIfq0A34+Eq5S/kf
58d+fhyEeYB7cMcT52UuIe7d/O5efv1t2UW8/+emhLhzvcfwTUrhyxjSN2Vn76bv5S7btXfpKDZx
v43xwXQ63YsxHqWmWe335i/Njy418Xhz++rRH37/u+O//PVvU10sK+xbYIV34ZTiW2+8Ft//8ONZ
e9u5dbtXbW737p1w7dq1Zuu5K5PdBw83u6aZNCk0sen3pTHNd6Sm6yb557UU0vVc0dv5o41BBLjT
LOS8NQ/Mp5dzkW/k5ytpUP1Rru3ZzvNpJ7++mT8oO9Bvzjd1H+SdIA97QlvOS75mt5sQt1LM7+uY
3sSTx2yX+ny9tHGo58n9HQAAAAAAAID6pfoPsGxQHL/bUfvkmId/3HEWF552IR3EGPfzEZXgcAmh
D/DYyu7a8TC/2M2v74UYd/Mnh6H3u24vPC3lWB7np/v5+csS5j45N6nv5c6Oct3v5+vlQUrdo65p
jtvU73OQSgY8hq7puuOd6y8cHvz38fGjR4+6nVu3V/7du3fvzPqSN19/Nbz3wUcpX4d2PWeV1yiM
fMTa84D8U24UgwzNF4MOzn8/C6ggQH/qVlBXmP70Xa7mYP2ie/oYg/bGNgAAAAAAAEBt0vgOuNJA
9llVBbTPnUWB7Z4eixD3egmBMwYCWjDY4drwQvMnN9fBBuefqCJAf3oGV1mY/tRtrt5g/fk7+piC
9ovGM4L3xnoAAAAAAAAMl2BeGFEA+6yqA9nnznI1Ae0Fp1Fgu48tTogbWE0/CbDuYfQwg/M/GNgM
PkD/Q9WF6U/PzCsO1p+7pY8naH9+NDPm4P3TxnfC+MbFAAAAAADA5ROS+78VNNKw9SKjCmCfawnV
BrIXnOZqAtqLjk1gu5+EuIEV9PkAXHzaM+wA/ZkBZlVh+h+qOlh/rlGOKWh/bjgz3uD94tGdMP7F
xsKC+uYZAAAAAAB8z18UllKJAtXPZNRh64UtZzQB7AVNodpA9qJjrSWgfa4FC2wDjGkYB8DY1RSm
PzMRqDZYf9aogvbnGvCYg/cLh3fC+M8+EhbUX/7cQpjfXA8AAAAAfiq/pb2USheWXhqB6ou0vNGG
rZ/SdEYTwF507LUGss+1+soC2mcJbAOMZtwCAPWqNVi/YAI3mqD9WaMO3i9s9ML4FxgKC+ovd2Yh
zN+P+Z0FAObtAAAAMEZ+C1XFSRR+vjTC0stuzQLVz970Rhu2flp9jCWAfe6qqTyQfZaANgAVjFsA
gCom5CMJ2i+YmI82eL+IMP5FLhpB/SVPLYT5L392ZwFAXXN1Cwm4jHYHAADLZEbKGhqZsHJNs1Lh
50u9moSll9ucBaovUFdjDVsvvBJHFsA+SyAbAAY1jgMAGLaxBu8XEcZ/doL6y74Qhfl7ML2zAKCe
mbqFBKyvtVnoAADA0n9FIAzM+mY0wspV9R7Cz5d7OQlLL7k+Baqf8cofedh6EQFsAGAgY14AAGoi
jP9sBPWXS5i/Dxe/BQAVTdUtJGBNTc1CBwAAlj7GFAZmjYSVK+s+hJ8vuf6FpZfYOwlUX4iwNQDA
IOcQAAAwToL6yyPMf/ksAKipc7KQgHWx0AEAgKVPaISBWd+MRli5uvMp/HyJvbew9NIJVAMAUPkc
DgAA4KcT5r9cFgDUw0IC1tdxW+gAAMByCQOz7vYmrFzRFFX4+dIJSwMAABeYkwMAAFADCwDqYCEB
62KhAwAAyyYMzDoJK9dH+BkAAGAY/DERAAAAesZCAtbBQgcAAJY+lxEGZv3zGmFlAAAAWDN/TQQA
AAAYKQsdAABYNmFgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAoCb/E2AAuplUaT6sEJcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" transform="matrix(0.24 0 0 0.24 -36 -36)">
    </image>
</g>
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, you are using a library which status is `Status: Unmaintained. Discontinued.` There are **other libraries** for managing SVG files. Anyway, in my opinion, you **don't need an SVG** at all. A simple **Android drawable** would do just fine.

Comment: Can u help me with that drawable..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: Ya i have seen these docs... but how to achieve the exact elliptical shadow?

Comment: and btw thanks for letting me know that the library is discontinued

Comment: You could use a 9 patch (which is a **stretchable** PNG). Or a GradientDrawable. Or a ShapeDrawable filled by a gradient. Maybe a LayerList is needed for the last 2 options. So, a 9 patch seems to be the easiest choice.

Comment: Is it advisable to use SVG inside and android app?

Comment: will you be able to post the code for the XML drawable... it will be very helpful for me... thank you

Comment: `Is it advisable to use SVG inside and android app?` Yes, to go beyond the limits of Android drawables. Google itself has implemented in Lollipop a new drawable, which is a **subset** of the SVG standard. But you should use SVGs only **if the game is worth the candle**. If you only need something that a little drawable is enough at, you don't need to add an external library and the extra code.

Comment: If you can be happy with a linear gradient... see this: http://envyandroid.com/archives/242/drawable-gradient-lines-android Just change the gradient colors to your liking (#00000000 to #ff000000 to #00000000).

Comment: is it possible to get exactly gradient like the one in the image?? It is a design requirement... :(

Comment: Sorry, I was messing with [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) materials... ;) I see you found a solution yourself, in the meanwhile. Great. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Der Golem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2649012/der-golem) i have found a solution to this problem by using a XML drawable... Here is the solution for getting an elliptic drop shadow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="180"
            android:pivotY="15%"
            android:toDegrees="0">

            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid
                    android:color="#ff000000"></solid>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```